# Mixing jquery with PHP

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery calendar in my cakephp application with

```
            <?php //foreach ($mealplans as $mealplan){ ?>
            { 
                title: '<?php echo $mealplan['Mealplan']['event_name'] . ", ". $mealplan['Mealplan']['total_calories']. " cals"; ?>',
                start: new Date(y, m, <?php
                $event = $mealplan['Mealplan']['event_date']; echo substr($event, 0, -8); ?>, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, 16),
                allDay: true,
                url: 'http://localhost/mealplans/view/1'
            },
            <?php //} ?>
```

When I uncomment foreach and its curly bracket at the end then it prints out the first of my meal plans on January 15 until January 16 but I want it to print out all of them. Most of the php is working in the jquery code it's just this one part that doesn't work. When I uncomment the foreach and its end bracket then the calendar disappears. You can see it at http://myownmealplanner.com/calendars/navigate The calendar code is from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/

Comment: When "the calendar disappears" what actually gets emitted to the browser?  Is there a JavaScript error?  What does the JavaScript look like when you use the loop vs. when you don't?  This doesn't sound like a problem with the PHP code (unless the data over which you're iterating doesn't contain what you think it does), more like a syntax problem with the resulting JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Some of the meal plans didn't have dates associated with them and thus the date code was corrupted. It works now at localhost.